# a Simple example of Busy Waiting in C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning *C# language* and I'm a beginner .

I want to implement a busy waiting by using threads in *C# language* .

I have read before below link, but there is a *C language* example code :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

Comment: so...you're looking for a simple wait/notify example?

Comment: yes, but by using threads .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you've provided is almost directly translatable into C#. The busy-wait (or spinlock) is implemented in `void *f1(void *p)`. This can be translated to C# thus:

```
static void f1()
{
    while (i == 0)
    {
    }

    Console.WriteLine("i's value has changed to {0}.", i);
    return;
}
```

I'd advise against using a hand-crafted spinlock unless you're absolutely sure what you're doing. If you need exclusive access to a variable, use the `lock` keyword to flag critical sections of code that use that variable.

Joe Albahari has posted an [excellent and free introduction to threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading). I'd strongly recommend reading this to gain a better understanding of threads and thread synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

So pixelbadger has posted an actual spinlock code for you.  Note though that this will ramp your CPU usage up to 100% since your while loop is just going as fast as it can.  (This is a problem with all spinlocks, from what I understand of them.  I never knew them by that name.)

A preferred way is to be notified when the value changes.  To that end, look at this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        // some random object to lock on
        private static Object objLock;

        // the value we want to read
        private static int value;

        // entry point
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            value = 0;
            objLock = new Object();

            // Backgrond worker runs on a new thread.
            BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
            // tells the background worker object that when it is run, it should execute the bgw_DoWork method below.
            bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
            // runs the background worker
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

            getValue();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void getValue()
        {
            // lock on our lock object so that no other thread can execute code that locks on the same object
            lock (objLock)
            {
                // Relinquishes the lock on our lock object.  This thread starts blocking ("paused")
                Monitor.Wait(objLock);
            }
            // Since the monitor Pulse(), we can continue execution.

            Console.WriteLine(value); // prints out 10 after the 2 second delay
        }

        static void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // some long operation that calculates the new value
            // this locks on our lock object.  since we Wait() on the objlock in getValue(), the lock is available and we
            // can continue executing this code.
            lock (objLock)
            {
                value = 10;
                // This tells the thread executing getValue() that it may continue.
                Monitor.Pulse(objLock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To reiterate, this is NOT a spinlock, but should accomplish the same result.